# Exporting Origin-Destination Matrix Table into Separate Origin and Destination Columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, network-analyst, network-dataset, origin-destination

Trying to work with exported data tables from Network Analyst of an origin-destination matrix for further network analysis like centrality measures...etc., but having to re-organize the origin and destination into their separate columns for other software like Python or NodeXL to perform well.

Is taking up quite a bit of time to do manually, does anyone know of any workarounds?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  The answer for rearranging geodatabase tables is often ArcPy update cursors, but before we can advise on that we will need to see what your input data looks like, what you seek in your output data, and what your code so far looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd like a rectangular matrix. This is one of non-scripting options.

```
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management("points_PointDistance", "INPUT_FID", "NEAR_FID", ..., in_z_field="DISTANCE")
```

Export events table into shapefile, **delete associated prj** file and add it to new mxd. Add geometry attributes and convert points to raster using Point_Z and cell size of 1. Replace NO DATA values by 0, using raster calculator and export result to ascii. This is how output text file will look like:

[image]